# Bootstrap Carousel Not Working I cant See 2nd image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My carousel from Bootstrap is not displaying my 2nd image ..it's only showing the first image.

Check out my [website](https://www.holyquranclasses.com/) for reference.

This is my HTML which I am using:

```
<div id="main-slide" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators visible-lg visible-md">
        <li data-target="#main-slide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#main-slide" data-slide-to="1"></li>

    </ol><!--/ Indicators end-->

    <!-- Carousel inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active" style="background-image:url(images/slider-main/image1.jpg)">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                                   <h1 class="slide-title-box animated4"> Some Text...</h1> 
                                  <div class="slide-title animated4"> Some Text...</div>
                     <div class="slide-title animated4"> Some Text... </div>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/ Carousel item 1 end -->

        <div class="item" style="background-image:url(images/slider-main/image2.jpg)">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                    <div class="slide-title-box animated4">Some Text...</div>
                    <div class="slide-title animated4">Some Text...</div>   
                    <div class="slide-title animated4">Some Text...</div>
                     <br>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/ Carousel item 2 end -->



    </div><!-- Carousel inner end-->

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#main-slide" data-slide="prev">
        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#main-slide" data-slide="next">
        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
    </a>
</div><!--/ Carousel end -->
```

Comment: When visiting the linked website, the javascript console indicates you have a partial copy of jquery.

Comment: hey can you please describe more ...